# Terminating App due to'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to search my array contents from the `TableView`,The Cells Have Detail View also.When i run my app in stimulator it runs but when i insert objects  dynamically and try to search them app crashes with '`NSInvalidArgumentException`'.
 reason:

```
'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <customcells: 0x8ea3b40> (not a collection)'.
```

My code which has Predicates is

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

self.searchedarray = nil;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.searchtext.text];

 self.searchedarray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray :[contactsarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

and also

```
  -(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

[searchedarray removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];    
searchedarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[contactsarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

}
```

Help me, I am stuck with this Predicate error ;Using Like instead of contains also doesn't help.

Edited content

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

 contactsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 self.searchedarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[contactsarray count]];

[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

}
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{



customcells *new = [[customcells alloc] init];
new.name = @"Enter Name";
new.contacts=@" Enter Contact Number";
new.organisation=@"Enter Organisation Name";
[contactsarray insertObject:new atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}



 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {

 // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {// Return the number of rows in the section.
 if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchedarray count];
  } else {
    return [contactsarray count];
 }

 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
customcells *myarray= [contactsarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = myarray.name;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                       myarray.name];

if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
   {
   customcells *newarray   = [searchedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text =newarray.name;
   } else {
       customcells *myarray= [contactsarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = myarray.name;
       cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                              myarray.name];       }
  }
       return cell;
 }



// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
   NSMutableArray *tempContent = [self.contactsarray mutableCopy];
    [tempContent removeObject:[tempContent                                                                objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   self.contactsarray = tempContent;
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }

 }


 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

 self.searchedarray = nil;

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.searchtext.text];

 self.searchedarray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray :[contactsarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
 }


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
 {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 customcells *new = contactsarray[indexPath.row];
 [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:new];
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
 }
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

[searchedarray removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];   
 searchedarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[contactsarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];


}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
// Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
// Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you please share `contactsarray` declaration and initialization?

Comment: @Keenle Please Check the edited content i have posted the code from .m and contacts array is a mutable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using 'contains' in the NSPredicate, which assumes that each element in your array can be matched using 'contains'. You have an array of `customcells`, which will not by default have any way of dealing with a contains matcher.

In your second example, using `self.name CONTAINS[c] %@`, you end up matching on the name property which is a string, so I would expect this to work (though I've not tried it). The first example you give is trying to match on the `customcells` object directly, so I'd suggest also using `self.name` in that case as well.